# Is there an efficient way to calculate log(a+b) using only log(a) and log(b) without using power law?

Tags: algorithms, logarithms

Is there an efficient way to calculate $\log(a+b) $ only using $\log(a) $ and $\log(b)$?

I am looking for an answer that does not involve powering.

Also, if there is a way for the general terms as well, please answer that as well.

Comment: We can get an estimation by AM-GM.

Comment: Why do you ask, and why the restriction? Is this for mental math? Is this on paper without calculator? Those insights are pertinent.

Comment: Interpolation will work, particularly if $a$ and $b$ are big.

Comment: I am using this in my program and my `double` type which cannot deal with very small numbers. Approximation is also ok.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe is solved by (Addition-Subtraction Logarithm)
 [Logarithmic number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_number_system) tables. They were introduced by Carl Gauss. Please read the Wikipedia article for references.